# How to avoid circular reference?

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, circular-reference

I'm using mySQL, and have such schema structure
Table Mark has refrences to date, student, subject, and teacher
and table teacher has many to many with subject.
So there is a mark-subject-tache circular refrence.
Is it acceptable, and how to avoid it if not?

Comment: I do not see anything circular here, take a look at similar questions:
https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A196713+circular

Answer (score 0):

Post is old but possibly this answer will help someone.

Normally, one needs to avoid circular references as this will create more problems later e.g. you won't be able to delete without making references null. Anyway, in some cases, you can have the circular references to make design compact.

In your case, you can treat Subject entity as master entity i.e. Subject will have its own independent lifecycle. By doing so, you will have many-to-one relationship from Mark to Subject and one-to-many unidirectional relationship from Teacher to Subject (this will require a link table between Teacher and Subject).